# Flutter - ReOrder Data Stored in FireStore

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, reorderable-list

[image]

As you can see, I am dragging Tasks by using ReorderableListView widget of Flutter.

The onReorder is able to drag the tasks up and down. However, when I close the app, all of the tasks go in the default order as it was arranged.

This is because my data which is being fetched from the CloudFireStore isn't changing its order, the way is it updated in my dragging.

**Can anyone help me, how can I update the position of tasks stored as documents in Cloud FireStore**, so that when I close the app and open it again, it shows new updated positions and not old positions of the task

[image]

The code :

```
child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("Tasks")
                        .doc(_email)
                        .collection("User_Tasks_List")
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading!...");
                      _docs = snapshot.data.documents;
                      return Theme(
                        data: ThemeData(canvasColor: Colors.transparent),
                        child: ReorderableListView(
                            children: _docs
                                .map((e) => InkWell(
                                    key: ObjectKey(e),
                                    onTap: () => _popupDialog(context, e),
                                    onDoubleTap: () => FirebaseFirestore
                                            .instance
                                            .runTransaction(
                                                (transaction) async {
                                          transaction.delete(e.reference);
                                          Fluttertoast.showToast(
                                              msg: "Task has been deleted!");
                                        }),
                                    child: ViewHolder(e)))
                                .toList(),
                            onReorder: onReorder),
                      );
                    }),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a parameter like `index:x` to items in firestore. Then you need to save the order of the ordered list items and store them in Firestore using the indexes.

When you fetch items you need to sort them by this index and you will get the same order.

```
objects.sort((a, b) => a.index.compareTo(b.index));
```

Comment: So I can't modify how it is stored in the firestore, whatever sorting or arrangement of data needs to be done, has to be done on client-side.

Comment: @Trizin 's answer is the correct approach. Nonetheless, if you don't want to modify the order on the database (which you should), you can still [persist data](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/persistence/key-value) on the client side. Once your app closes you should store the document IDs with it's order and when retrieved again, reorder it yourself. Bear in mind that when retrieving the same information from another client the ordering will be the original one as saved in Firestore.